# Hide Header(Li section inside) with TRUE or FALSE result

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have this HTML header with `<nav><ul><li>` sections , the problem is that I'm trying to hide the **`LI`** section with id **`recfAct`** when in my CodeBehind **brpt** gets false

**HTML**

```
<header class="header" id="header1">
    <h2>LISTADO tabla [TParUsuPerfil]</h2>
     <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li id="refAct"><a href="Update/UpdateS.aspx">Actualizar</a> </li>
                <li id="refSalir"><a href="Contenido1.aspx">Salir</a> </li>                         
            </ul>
        </nav>
</header>
```

**C#**

```
Boolean bRpt;
bRpt = wsObj.ValidarExiste(Session["LoginUsername"].ToString()); //gets false or true in brpt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : 
Just need to add the tag **runat ="server"** and then i can call it in code behind

```
Html:
<li id="refAct" runat="server"><a href="Update/UpdateS.aspx">Actualizar</a> </li>
<li id="refSalir"><a href="Contenido1.aspx">Salir</a> </li>
```

```
CodeBehind:
 refAct.Visible = true;
```